How is Binary Search Θ(logn)?
I'm currently studying algorithm analysis and have a question about the time complexity of Binary Search. I understand that the worst-case time complexity of Binary Search is O(logn) based on the recurrence relation T(n).
However, I’m confused about the conditions under which Binary Search is considered to have a time complexity of Θ(logn). Specifically, I understand that for an algorithm to be Θ(logn), it must be both O(logn) in the worst case and Ω(logn) in the best case.
But isn’t the best-case time complexity of Binary Search actually O(1), since the best-case scenario occurs when the target is found on the first try? How does this reconcile with the overall Θ(logn) complexity? Am I missing something in my analysis of T(n) or the definition of Θ notation?
I would appreciate any clarification or guidance on this, especially if there’s a simple concept I might be overlooking.

In the best case for any binary search your first comparison is an exact match on the target (and some languages support a 3 way branch for <,=,>). Worst case you aim to split the total  range into two nearly equal parts and know which half contains the target value.  Sometimes you do get lucky.

@MartinBrown I don't see many binary searches checking for = because it doesn't help most of the time, and ends up adding extra overhead for each step of the process.  In C++ your objects don't even need to support == or >, only <.

Who said it's Θ(logn)? What version of binary search were they talking about?

@MarkRansom after the compare it branches depending on the condition codes for < or > and drops through for exactly equal. This trick dates way back to the computed if statement  in FORTRAN II and Dec's FOCAL interpreter. There are exactly the same number of branches for the dumb as a rock code that does < and an unconditional branch. The three way split can finish more quickly.

@nocomment they were referring to pseudocode of an iterative binary search

Still matters what version it was. Note that Matt's answer is wrong in one or two ways.

I think this question is really "what do people mean when they say an algorithm is Theta(f)". There might be a dominant interpretation of this ambiguous statement (Matt's answer seems to suggest that they think so), but it's for sure ambiguous. If it's a context where it matters, then it's better to say for example "the worst case number of comparisons in binary search is Theta(log n)" and avoid the need to guess the missing details.

Are you going to show us that pseudocode?

You are incorrect here: "I understand that for an algorithm to be Θ(logn), it must be both O(logn) in the worst case and Ω(logn) in the best case"
Both bounds apply to the worst case: For an algorithm to be Θ(logn), it must be both O(logn) in the worst case and Ω(logn) in the worst case.
(Don't tell me about all the places you've seen contradictory information on the web.  A lot of people get this wrong.)

Thank you! This was a clarification I needed, I kept getting mixed information everywhere.

Matt, is this a case of "people get this wrong"?

@nocomment no.  It's a little pedantic, but it's not wrong.

Doesn't it contradict what you're saying and imply the OP's "incorrect" statement?

No.  It gives an accurate example of something that is incorrect to say, and one of the reasons why it's wrong, but it doesn't define what it means for "an algorithm to be Θ(logn)".  In fact a statement like "Algorithm X is Θ(log n)" is always incorrect, because it's sloppy.  X is an algorithm and Θ(log n) is a set of functions so of course the algorithm is not the set.  But we should try to understand what we read instead of picking nits.  If we read "X is Θ(log n)" we should understand it to mean that there is a function f(n) related to X that is in Θ(log n), and that function is...?
